# How to submit a form data using Jquery ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This Jquery code isn't displaying my error message atleast... Each time i submit the form i expect a success or error message but it doesn't seem like it is responding...

```
<form method="POST" id="comment_form">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your comment" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="submit"> 
</div>
</form>
<span id="comment_message"></span>
```

//add_comment.php page

```
<?php require_once("../include/database.php"); ?>
<?php
$error = $comment_name = $comment_content = "";

if(empty($_POST["comment_name"])){
    $error .= '<p class="text-danger">Name is required</p>';
}else{
    $comment_name = $_POST["comment_name"];
}

if(empty($_POST["comment_content"])){
    $error .= '<p class="text-danger">Comment is required</p>';
}else{
    $comment_content = $_POST["comment_content"];
}

if($error == ''){
//  $comments = new Comment();
//  $comments->parent_comment_id   = $_POST["comment_id"];
//  $comments->comment             = $comments;
//  $comments->comment_sender_name = $comment_name;
//  $comments->save();  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (parent_comment_id, comment, comment_sender_name)
    VALUES (:parent_comment_id, :comment, :comment_sender_name)";
    $statement = $database->query($sql = array(
      ':parent_comment_id'   => $_POST["comment_id"],
      ':comment'             => $comment_content,
      ':comment_sender_name' => $comment_name
    )
    );
$error = '<label class="text-success">Comment Added</label>';   
}
$data = array(
    'error'   => $error
);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

//Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
        url:"add_comment.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{form_data:form_data},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            if(data.error != ''){
                $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
                $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
            }
        }
    });
 });
});
```

Please i need to know why the submit button isn't responding...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The necessary bootstrap and jquery libraries were added...

Comment: Try Logging the Response from server. What you are getting? Try `console.log(data)` inside the Ajax success callback and check the error message in Browser console.

Comment: Your database query call doesn't look correct to me, though of course I don't know what database class you are using. It seems that you create a query string and assign it to the `$sql` variable, then overwrite that in your call to `query()`. If you add an `error` function to your Ajax, do you get anything in that?

Comment: @droopsnoot database connection is correct... i have used the connection severally...